# Can send data but request.getParameter always == null

Tags: java, xml, servlets

There are my code from java eclipse keplero, my project was a servlet(server) that communicate with extension of chrome(client) via XMLRequest. I have used GET and POST and servlet can comunicate the string in between case but request.getParameter was in every case null.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>XMLFinal</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "get" action = "main">
Data: <input type="text" name="data">
<input type="submit" value = "send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

main.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class main
 */
@WebServlet("/main")
public class main extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
public main() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

//server funziona in invio, il segnale in ricezione non funziona ancora
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    //guardare file index.html
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("data"));



    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    //
    response.getWriter().write("GET");

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //guardare file index.html
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("data"));



    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    //invio segnale funzionante 
    response.getWriter().write("POST2");
}

private void getHeadersInfo() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

I have improve in login page to create a simple form and that run perfectly but i need data from js client :

```
loadXMLRequest();

function loadXMLRequest()
{
    var xmlhttp;

//da testare su Chrome Firefox Opera IE 7 o superiore
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //arrivo del segnale
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/XMLFinal/main?ciao",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/plain");
    alert("questi sono  i dati da inviare : ciao"");

    xmlhttp.send();
    alert("Message sent");

    //apertura pagina web risposta giunta ed in elaborazione
    //window.open(xmlhttp.responseText);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==0)
        {
            alert("request not initialized");
        }

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==1)
        {
            alert("server connection established");
        }

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==2)
        {
            alert("request received");
        }

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==3)
        {
            alert("processing request");
        }

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        {
            alert("request finished and response is ready");
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

            //nessun dato ricevuto possibile shutdown del server
            if(xmlhttp.responseText=="")
            {

            }
            else
            {
                //windows.open(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==200)
        {
            alert("OK");
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==404)
        {
            alert("Page not found");
        }
    }


}
else
{
    //per IE 6 o inferiore
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    alert("Microsoft alert");
}
```

}

Comment: Why should it return anything other than `null`?

Comment: Don't use 'main' as a class name. Only causes confusion. And capitalize your class names, again to avoid confusion.

Comment: i have changed code class name wherever is necessary but the mistake remain

Comment: Ok i have solved i add the string in send(data) and in url+"?"+data

Answer (score 1):

#### The Name is the Key

Your code says

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("http"));
```

and your form says

```
<input type="text" name="data">
```

Change the first to

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("data"));
```

**or** the second to

```
<input type="text" name="http">
```

Comment: i have already used data in previous text but they didnt work return null with client and return correct name from form

Answer (score 0):

You are making a Get call i.e.,

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/XMLFinal/main?ciao",true);
```

So from servlet it will call `doGet(-,-)` method, but under `doGet(-,-)` method you have written

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("http"));
```

which should be replaced like

```
System.out.println(request.getParameter("data"));
```

Which you have correctly written in `doPost(-,-)` method.

But i always prefer not to write redundant code. in both `doGet()` & `doPost()`, instead you can write code in a common method and call the same method from both the do*** methods. i.e.,

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: i have used in previous text data how i make in doPost but they return null from xmlRequest and a right string from form

Comment: If you want to make it in `doPost()` method then change your Java Script code like below `xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/XMLFinal/main?ciao",true);`